# Fading in background image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you fade in a background image (the body tag, and it is tiled) with jQuery? The background color is white and in a callback function I want to toggle the background image to on and off.

Any ideas?

Comment: It might have been worth trying Google first.

Answer (score 0):

[Using jQuery for Background Image Animations](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/)

Comment: That looks great. Trying it out now. Will comment in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't really fade in a tiled background image. Since the image is part of the CSS rendering system it doesn't have a node in the DOM.

You can do some fancy stuff by using a frame type animation by moving the position of the background image but this wouldn't work with:

```
A. a whole body background
B. a tiled image.
```