# How to add fade effect to jquery css background image

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

```
$('#mob-display-feature').css("background-image",'url('+"./images/large/1.jpg"+')');
```

Please let me know how I can add fade effect to above jquery code. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "add fade effect" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319552/can-i-fade-in-a-background-image-css-background-image-with-jquery

Comment: I need to add .fadeIn(); to that peice of code.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link to know more:
http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Just copy, paste and try it. Hope this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>fade effect</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   margin: 0;
  }

  div.myimage{
   width: 500px;
   height: 400px;
   box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px black;
   border:1px solid black;
   
  }

  div.imge{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url(http://zelcs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/stackoverflow-logo-dumpster.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
   display: none;
  }
 </style>
<body>

 <div class="myimage"><div class="imge"></div></div>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myimage").mouseenter(function(){
   $(".imge").fadeIn(1000);
  });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myimage").mouseleave(function(){
   $(".imge").fadeOut(1000);
  });
 });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) or [fadein](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) after having added your CSS `background-image` property.

You can add additional code in the callback function for those effects (marked in the example with `// animation complete.`) this will allow you execute your code after animation ends.

I would suggest you to keep `background-image` directly in CSS and remove jQuery CSS code, if you have no reasons to add this property dynamically with JS.

```
#mob-display-featurey {
    background-image: url("url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200");
}
```

---

Example:

```js
// background-imag 
$('#mob-display-feature').css("background-image", "url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/)");

// on click start animation fadeout
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#mob-display-feature").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    // animation complete.
  });
});
```

```css
#mob-display-feature {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mob-display-feature">mob-display-feature</div>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `fadeIn` effect when displaying image dynamically.

HTML:

```
<div id="image-holder">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image-holder
{
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#image-holder').css('background-image','url(http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/859/sunset-1378816.jpg)').fadeIn("slow");
```