# Background image not fading in

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image, fading

I've been trying to figure out why my background image is not fading in. I've tried using css/jquery and also the w3 route. I can see that the background image is actually showing up and I have checked to see that the jquery code is actually working for any tags I nest inside the body tag. I have read other posts but they are not helping.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").hide().fadeIn(3000);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('../images/index.jpeg');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/myScript.js"></script>
</head>


<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try after removing `hide()` . Like `$("body").fadeIn(3000);`

Comment: Just tried but not working.

Comment: Not sure if CSS/jquery is conflicting soewhere

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319552/can-i-fade-in-a-background-image-css-background-image-with-jquery

Comment: look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3h8buLwx/1/). Is this what you want?

Comment: I tried with your `body` class. It is working with me. May be some issue in some .js or .css file. Add reference of .css and .js one by one. So you can identify from which file issue occurs.

Comment: Thank you Shadow Fiend it worked. Why does that css code differ greatly from the one I had originally?

Comment: i just change the body tag to the div and set the height.. those are the important changes.. the other things are just bonus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I fade in a background image (CSS: background-image) with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319552/can-i-fade-in-a-background-image-css-background-image-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").hide().fadeIn(3000);
});
```

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

div{
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/science/photos/000/009/940.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3871288  In this the fade is working on the body.All the content inside the body will fade in.The background image is inside a div inside the body.It is not the background image that fades in.

Comment: before I also tried body tag but won't work.. so I made a div as the container of the page and add a fade in.. I don't know if you can make another approach..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimout`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("body").css("background-image", "url('https://s13.favim.com/orig/170403/aesthetic-forest-nature-photography-Favim.com-5145568.png')");
}, 2000);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>just text here</p>
```